# How to restore classic Libreoffice 4 color palette (actually 5.2) (highlight colors, font colors, etc.) for use in Libreoffice 5 or 6 or later

Tags: colors, libreoffice

In 2017 or so (see here: https://design.blog.documentfoundation.org/2017/04/10/new-standard-color-palette/), LibreOffice decided to get rid of their LibreOffice 4.3 color palette, with the nice, bright greens ("Green 1", "Green 2", and "Green 3") that I liked so much, for instance, and they replaced it with a new palette. I think it's a tragedy that they got rid of the old palettes rather than just adding new ones, but that's what they did. Anyway, I missed the 4.3 template.

After 1.5+ years of not knowing how to get the old template back, I finally figured it out. I'll post this as an answer to share it with others, as I've seen a few other forums and things where people want to know.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated 30 Aug. 2020: how to install LibreOffice 5.2 classic color palette in any OS (Windows, Mac, Linux):

*Tested in LibreOffice 6.4.5.2 in Ubuntu 20.04.*

Just go here: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/libreoffice-5-2-color-palette --> click the "Download" button ([direct link here](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/assets/downloads/z/libo-5-2-colorpalette.oxt)). Save the "**libo-5-2-colorpalette.oxt**" extension installation file somewhere. Double-click it to run and install it. That's it! Works perfectly!

Now, simply select this color palette from the menus! It is called **LibreOffice 5.2**, as shown below:

[image]

Ah, so much better!

[image]

"Green 2" is one of my favorite highlight colors:

[image]

---

**OLD/OBSOLETE ANSWER:**

## Linux Instructions:

Here's the old Libreoffice 4.3 `standard.soc` color palette file taken from: `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/config/standard.soc`, on an Ubuntu 14.04 laptop which originally had LibreOffice 4 on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ooo:color-table xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"><draw:color draw:name="Black" draw:color="#000000"/><draw:color draw:name="White" draw:color="#ffffff"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 1" draw:color="#eeeeee"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 2" draw:color="#dddddd"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 3" draw:color="#cccccc"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 4" draw:color="#b2b2b2"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 5" draw:color="#999999"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 6" draw:color="#808080"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 7" draw:color="#666666"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 8" draw:color="#333333"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 9" draw:color="#1c1c1c"/><draw:color draw:name="Gray 10" draw:color="#111111"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow" draw:color="#ffff99"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange" draw:color="#ff6600"/><draw:color draw:name="Red" draw:color="#ff3333"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink" draw:color="#ff00cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta" draw:color="#ff33ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple" draw:color="#9900ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue" draw:color="#6666ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue" draw:color="#00ccff"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan" draw:color="#66ffff"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise" draw:color="#33ff99"/><draw:color draw:name="Green" draw:color="#99ff66"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green" draw:color="#ccff00"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 1" draw:color="#ffff66"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 1" draw:color="#ffcc00"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 1" draw:color="#ff9999"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 1" draw:color="#ff66cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 1" draw:color="#ff99ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 1" draw:color="#cc66ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 1" draw:color="#9999ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 1" draw:color="#9999ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 1" draw:color="#99ffff"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 1" draw:color="#66ff99"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 1" draw:color="#99ff99"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 1" draw:color="#ccff66"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 2" draw:color="#ffff00"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 2" draw:color="#ff9900"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 2" draw:color="#ff6666"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 2" draw:color="#ff3399"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 2" draw:color="#ff66ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 2" draw:color="#9933ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 2" draw:color="#3333ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 2" draw:color="#3399ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 2" draw:color="#00ffff"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 2" draw:color="#00ff66"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 2" draw:color="#66ff66"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 2" draw:color="#99ff33"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 3" draw:color="#cc9900"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 3" draw:color="#ff3300"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 3" draw:color="#ff0000"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 3" draw:color="#ff0066"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 3" draw:color="#ff00ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 3" draw:color="#6600ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 3" draw:color="#0000ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 3" draw:color="#0066ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 3" draw:color="#00cccc"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 3" draw:color="#00cc33"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 3" draw:color="#00cc00"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 3" draw:color="#66ff00"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 4" draw:color="#996600"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 4" draw:color="#cc3300"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 4" draw:color="#cc0000"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 4" draw:color="#cc0066"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 4" draw:color="#cc00cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 4" draw:color="#6600cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 4" draw:color="#0000cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 4" draw:color="#0066cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 4" draw:color="#009999"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 4" draw:color="#009933"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 4" draw:color="#009900"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 4" draw:color="#66cc00"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 5" draw:color="#663300"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 5" draw:color="#801900"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 5" draw:color="#990000"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 5" draw:color="#990066"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 5" draw:color="#990099"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 5" draw:color="#330099"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 5" draw:color="#000099"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 5" draw:color="#006699"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 5" draw:color="#006666"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 5" draw:color="#007826"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 5" draw:color="#006600"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 5" draw:color="#669900"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 6" draw:color="#333300"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 6" draw:color="#461900"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 6" draw:color="#330000"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 6" draw:color="#330033"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 6" draw:color="#660066"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 6" draw:color="#000033"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 6" draw:color="#000066"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 6" draw:color="#000080"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 6" draw:color="#003333"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 6" draw:color="#00331a"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 6" draw:color="#003300"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 6" draw:color="#193300"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 7" draw:color="#666633"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 7" draw:color="#661900"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 7" draw:color="#663333"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 7" draw:color="#660033"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 7" draw:color="#663366"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 7" draw:color="#330066"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 7" draw:color="#333366"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 7" draw:color="#003366"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 7" draw:color="#336666"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 7" draw:color="#006633"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 7" draw:color="#336633"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 7" draw:color="#336600"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 8" draw:color="#999966"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 8" draw:color="#996633"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 8" draw:color="#996666"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 8" draw:color="#993366"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 8" draw:color="#996699"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 8" draw:color="#663399"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 8" draw:color="#666699"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 8" draw:color="#336699"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 8" draw:color="#669999"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 8" draw:color="#339966"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 8" draw:color="#669966"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 8" draw:color="#669933"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 9" draw:color="#cccc99"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 9" draw:color="#cc9966"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 9" draw:color="#cc9999"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 9" draw:color="#cc6699"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 9" draw:color="#cc99cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 9" draw:color="#9966cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 9" draw:color="#9999cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 9" draw:color="#6699cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 9" draw:color="#99cccc"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 9" draw:color="#66cc99"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 9" draw:color="#99cc99"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 9" draw:color="#99cc66"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow 10" draw:color="#ffffcc"/><draw:color draw:name="Orange 10" draw:color="#ffcc99"/><draw:color draw:name="Red 10" draw:color="#ffcccc"/><draw:color draw:name="Pink 10" draw:color="#ff99cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Magenta 10" draw:color="#ffccff"/><draw:color draw:name="Purple 10" draw:color="#cc99ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue 10" draw:color="#ccccff"/><draw:color draw:name="Sky blue 10" draw:color="#99ccff"/><draw:color draw:name="Cyan 10" draw:color="#ccffff"/><draw:color draw:name="Turquoise 10" draw:color="#99ffcc"/><draw:color draw:name="Green 10" draw:color="#ccffcc"/><draw:color draw:name="Yellow green 10" draw:color="#ccff99"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue gray" draw:color="#e6e6ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Blue classic" draw:color="#cfe7f5"/><draw:color draw:name="Violet" draw:color="#9999ff"/><draw:color draw:name="Bordeaux" draw:color="#993366"/><draw:color draw:name="Pale yellow" draw:color="#ffffcc"/><draw:color draw:name="Pale green" draw:color="#ccffcc"/><draw:color draw:name="Dark violet" draw:color="#660066"/><draw:color draw:name="Salmon" draw:color="#ff8080"/><draw:color draw:name="Sea blue" draw:color="#0066cc"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 1" draw:color="#004586"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 2" draw:color="#ff420e"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 3" draw:color="#ffd320"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 4" draw:color="#579d1c"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 5" draw:color="#7e0021"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 6" draw:color="#83caff"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 7" draw:color="#314004"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 8" draw:color="#aecf00"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 9" draw:color="#4b1f6f"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 10" draw:color="#ff950e"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 11" draw:color="#c5000b"/><draw:color draw:name="Chart 12" draw:color="#0084d1"/><draw:color draw:name="Tango: Sky Blue 1" draw:color="#729fcf"/><draw:color draw:name="Tango: Sky Blue 2" draw:color="#3465a4"/><draw:color draw:name="Ubuntu Orange" draw:color="#dd4814"/><draw:color draw:name="Ubuntu Warm Grey" draw:color="#aea79f"/><draw:color draw:name="Ubuntu Cool Grey" draw:color="#333333"/><draw:color draw:name="Ubuntu Light Aubergine" draw:color="#77216f"/><draw:color draw:name="Ubuntu Mid Aubergine" draw:color="#5e2750"/><draw:color draw:name="Ubuntu Dark Aubergine" draw:color="#2c001e"/><draw:color draw:name="Canonical Aubergine" draw:color="#772953"/></ooo:color-table>
```

Forget about it's weird one-line XML format: that's how LibreOffice likes it.

Here's what it looked like inside LibreOffice:

[image]

Notice that beautiful, bright shade of "Green 2" that I love so much, that they removed from LibreOffice 5 and 6 in their folly.

Simply copy and paste the "standard.soc" XML content above into a text file and save it as `standard_old.soc`.

Now, on your new computer (ex: running LibreOffice 6 in Ubuntu 18.04) find the location of your color palette `*.soc` files:

```
cd / && find | grep libreoffice.*\.soc
```

You might have results something like this. This reveals that the location where your new Libreoffice color palettes are stored is "/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/". You'll need to know this directory for the next part.

```
./usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/standard.soc
./usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/html.soc
./usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/freecolour-hlc.soc
./usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/tonal.soc
./usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/libreoffice.soc
./usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/chart-palettes.soc
```

Finally, copy the old color template from `standard_old.soc` (that you just made above) into the folder you discovered just above:

```
sudo cp path/to/standard_old.soc /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/palette/standard_old.soc
```

Done! Close and re-open LibreOffice and this most beautiful and treasured color palette will be available as "standard_old" from the color palette dropdown menu when you go to choose a color.

## Windows Instructions:

Unknown, but probably something similar to the above process. Feel free to pitch in and write a comment or answer to show how to do it in Windows.

Comment: Linux instructions helped me to restore 6.x palette after upgrading to 7.x. It is interesting that the palette is called "standard" but keep changing.

Answer (score 2):

Out-dated palettes are saved on the LibreOffice extension site:

- Standard https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/libreoffice-5-2-color-palette
- Tango https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/tango-color-variations
- Breeze https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/breeze-color-palette

And some background info is on the LibreOffice design blog https://design.blog.documentfoundation.org/?s=palette

Comment: I just tried this solution (configuring a new computer). Works nice! I was surprised to see that just clicking on the downloaded .oxt file automatically installed the extension into LibreOffice. Thanks!